# Controlling one JFrame from another jframe while opening third jframe in java

Tags: java, jframe

I have 3 different JFrames. One `Jframe` is a login page another has `progressbar` and the third one is main page. Now what i want is that when we login in I want to show `progressbar` above login page and on completing progress to 100% I want to close both frames and open third `Jframe` which is main page. please kindly help me get this done.
Thanks
//here is the code part.

```
rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
    if(rs.next()){
    progressbar prb=new progressbar(user);
    prb.setVisible(true);
```

}// this open my 2nd JFrame of progress bar

//next in Progressbar page i have this code

```
`public progressbar(String user) {
    initComponents();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    t = new Timer(35, (ActionEvent e) -> {
        count++;
        pb.setValue(count);
        if(pb.getValue()<100){
            pb.setValue(pb.getValue() + 1); // it makes bar progress
        }
// after progress is 100%
        if(pb.getValue()== 100){
            t.stop();
            this.dispose(); 
            Mainpage mp=new Mainpage(user);
            mp.setVisible(true); // this opens my Mainpage
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

// Now what I want is after progress bar completes, I want to dispose both the login page and progress bar page opening Main page only

Comment: Which part of this do you need help with? Post code please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice

Comment: This use case sounds like an abuse of JFrame. A separate JFrame just for your login progress bar?

Comment: yeah that is, but I too dont want to do it that way. If you have another option for showing progress bar while login is valid and then redirect it to main page... then please help me.

Comment: Check out the link that Reimeus posted. The answers there talk in depth about why you should only ever have ONE JFrame, and better ways to handle multiple pages.

Answer (score 1):

For closing JFrames use command `yourFrame.dispose();` Setting progressBar to 100% is easy via `yourBar.setValue(yourBar.getMaximum());`  To hide/show components use `name.setVisible(true);`  I won't use separate JFrame only for progress bar by the way.

I can recommend you reading some [doc about JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html). If you want more specific answer, please post your code here.

Comment: but I want to use progress bar as separate pop up above Login page while login is successful. If we have some ideas doing it another way from same Login page then please I would be grateful to use that concept. and please note that I am a beginner. :D :) and I have mentioned code in my question above

Comment: I'm not an expert, I'm pretty much beginner too. I would use `dispose()` method to closing both your JFrames. I don't know how they're called (you're closing progressbar frame via `this.dispose();` which should be right. But you're making it very complicated when you're using 3 different JFrames. I would move progressBar to your first JFrame.

Comment: I want to do exactly the same. moving progress bar to the same Login JFrame but want it look like a different popup frame above login page and then redirect to Mainpage. is there any way we can do that ??

Comment: You can put progress bar on the login JFrame and after inicialization set it to invisible `progressBar.setVisible(false);` and then, when you want to "pop up" only set it to `setVisible(true);` and it will look like pop up. If i get your idea right :P

Comment: do you mean this
if(rs.next()){
pb.setVisible(true);

 t = new Timer(30, (ActionEvent e) -> {
            count++;
            pb.setValue(count);
            if(pb.getValue()<100){
                pb.setValue(pb.getValue() + 1);
            }
            if(pb.getValue()== 100){
                t.stop();
                this.dispose();
                Mainpage mp=new Mainpage(user);
                mp.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        t.start();*/

I have done this way, but it looks little odd. may be I am feeling like that :)

Comment: Yeah, pretty much like this. There's another way to do it, but it doesn't look like pop up. You can only **disable** the progressbar. That means, after inicialization, you'll set `pb.setEnabled(false);` and when you want to show it you'll switch to `pb.setEnabled(true);`.  Before enabling it will be gray. But I guess that's not what you want.